# Load a driver before username/ password login screen on a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, drivers, login, tablet

I have a Wacom Intuos tablet and am trying to load the driver/ functionality so that I can use it at the Mac login screen (to enter my username and password). At present only my keyboard (and mouse) works at this stage.

Another knock on issues is that I have to have a mouse plugged in at all times as this seems to be a mandatory Mac requirement. It is possible to disable the function but I presume that if the tablet is enabled then this not be necessary.

A couple of companies I have freelanced in have this feature enabled and it's a really nice touch.

Thank you,

Tom

Comment: Are you certain that they have this from cold-boot, & not just after a machine's been logged in, then logged out again?

Comment: Yes. The tablet would work from a cold boot.